# Start a GNU screen window in the background/without focus

Tags: gnu-screen

The following command `screen -t 'fubar' cmd` will create a new screen window with the command cmd running in it and will set the focus to this window.

How can I keep the focus in the current screen window, not the new one?

Comment: I do not know how to solve your precise problem, but you can try to create a new detached screen in your screen with something like: `screen -t 'fubar' -d -m cmd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do it in one go, here is a workaround:

```
screen -t 'fubar' cmd & sleep .01; screen -X other
```

Comment: `screen -X other` does indeed return me to the first screen which is what I wanted.  Nice workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a current screen session, this will start your command in a new screen window and then immediately switch back to your previous screen window, effectively backgrounding the new screen window.

Enter the screen command line with `Ctrl-a :` and enter

`eval 'screen top' 'other'`

`eval` parses and executes each argument as a separate command. So the first command is to run `top` in a new screen window and the second command is toggle to the window displayed previously.